# Is there a 100% completion guide for GTA Chinatown Wars for iPhone?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-chinatown-wars

I've just completed the main storyline for *GTA: Chinatown Wars* on my iPhone and I am currently sitting around 60% complete.

Is there anywhere I can find a list of things that I need to do to complete the game?

I understand this would mean finding all the dealers, completing all the minigames, etc., but I would like a complete list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an helpful checklist, so you can check as you go ([source](https://gtaforums.com/topic/403855-chinatown-wars-100-checklist/)):

```
GTA Chinatown Wars Checklist
Main Missions
[ ] Yu Jian 
[ ] Pursuit Farce
[ ] Under the Gun   
[ ] Payback
[ ] The Wheelman    
[ ] Tricks of the Triad
[ ] Natural Burn Killer 
[ ] Recruitment Drive
[ ] Carpe 'Dime'    
[ ] Store Wars
[ ] Copter Carnage  
[ ] Kenny Strikes Back
[ ] Missed the Boat?    
[ ] Rat Race
[ ] Pimp His Ride   
[ ] Whack the Racers
[ ] Jackin' Chan    
[ ] Raw Deal
[ ] Sa-boat-age 
[ ] Counterfeit Gangster
[ ] Slaying with Fire   
[ ] Clear the Pier
[ ] Stealing the Show   
[ ] Flatliner
[ ] Bomb Disposal   
[ ] Driven to Destruction
[ ] Cash and Burn   
[ ] Dragon Haul Z
[ ] The Fandom Menace   
[ ] So Near, Yet Sonar
[ ] Hit from the Tong   
[ ] Trail Blazer
[ ] The Offshore Offload    
[ ] One Shot, One Kill
[ ] By Myriads of Swords
[ ] A Shadow of Doubt
[ ] Friend or Foe?
[ ] Arms Out of Harm's Way
[ ] The Wages of Hsin   
[ ] A Rude Awakening
[ ] The Tow Job 
[ ] The Tail Bagging the Dogs
[ ] Weapon of Mass Distraction  
[ ] Street of Rage
[ ] Operation Northwood
[ ] Torpedo Run
[ ] Scrambled   
[ ] Evidence Dash
[ ] Wi-Find 
[ ] Salt in the Wound
[ ] Double Trouble  
[ ] Faster Pusher Man! Sell! Sell!
[ ] Convoy Conflict 
[ ] See No Evil
[ ] Grave Situation 
[ ] Steal the Wheels
[ ] The World's a Stooge    
[ ] Oversights
Percentage  ?.??%

Random Pedestrians

[ ] Wilhelm 
[ ] Wilhelm 2
[ ] Wilhelm 3   
[ ] Guy
[ ] Selma 1 
[ ] Selma 2
[ ] Giorgio 1   
[ ] Giorgio 2
[ ] Tommy 1 
[ ] Tommy 2
[ ] Marcy 1 
[ ] Marcy 2
[ ] Cherie  
[ ] Alonso
Percentage  ?.??%

Earn 85 Medals  Note: Any medal is good enough
See the Reward Section at the bottom for Gold Medal rewards

Odd Jobs

[ ] Police Missions
Complete 5 levels
(100% kill rate)

[ ] Ambulance Missions
Complete 5 waves
(100% save rate)

[ ] Firetruck Missions
Gold Medal

[ ] Taxi Missions
Complete 15 Fares

[ ] Fast Tracks
[ ] HoboTron

[ ] Noodle Run
Algonquin

[ ] Noodle Run
Dukes

[ ] Excess Delivery
Alpha Mail

[ ] Excess Delivery
Liberty State Delivery

[ ] Most Tattoos in a row
Percentage  ?.??%

Time Trials

[ ] Go-Kar-TT Course 1
[ ] Go-Kar-TT Course 2
[ ] Go-Kar-TT Course 3
[ ] Go-Kar-TT Course 4
[ ] Boulevard Boogie TT Course 1
[ ] Boulevard Boogie TT Course 2
[ ] Boulevard Boogie TT Course 3
[ ] Boulevard Boogie TT Course 4
[ ] Wetscapade TT Course 1
[ ] Wetscapade TT Course 2
[ ] Wetscapade TT Course 3
[ ] Wetscapade TT Course 4
[ ] Patriot Park TT Course 1
[ ] Patriot Park TT Course 2
[ ] Patriot Park TT Course 3
[ ] Patriot Park TT Course 4
[ ] Dukes Dust Up TT Course 1
[ ] Dukes Dust Up TT Course 2
[ ] Dukes Dust Up TT Course 3
[ ] Loose Exchange
[ ] Midtown Mayhem
[ ] East Side Escapade
[ ] Graveyard Groove
[ ] Beach Blitz
[ ] Monument Mania
[ ] Bohan Snake
Percentage  ?.??%

Street Races
S&M Grand Slam

[ ] Bohan Classic
[ ] Bohan Rally

Transfender Invitational

[ ] Algonquin Auto-trial
[ ] Star Junction Circuit
[ ] Middle Park Motivator

Hi-Way Tire Tourney

[ ] Schlotter Sweep
[ ] Broker Open
[ ] Dukes Dynamo
Percentage  ?.??%

L.C. Gun Club

[ ] Pistol Medal
[ ] SMG Medal
[ ] Shotgun Medal
[ ] Grenade Medal
[ ] Sniper Medal
Percentage  ?.??%

Riding Shotgun

[ ] Industrial
[ ] Willis
[ ] Beechwood City
[ ] Purgatory
[ ] Suffolk 
Percentage  ?.??%

Rampages

[ ] East Island City Twin Pistols
[ ] Steinway Flame thrower
[ ] Northern Gardens Flame thrower
[ ] Northwood Assault Rifle
[ ] Happiness Island minigun
[ ] Castle Gardens Carbine Rifle
[ ] Northwood Chainsaw
[ ] The Meat Quarter RPG
[ ] Northwood Carbine Rifle
[ ] Lancaster Flame thrower
[ ] Hatton Gardens Assault Rifle
[ ] South Bohan Flame thrower
[ ] Westminster Stubby shotgun
[ ] Middle Park Shotgun
[ ] Meadows Park Double barreled shotgun
[ ] Meadow Hills Micro SMG
[ ] Boulevard unarmed
[ ] Willis SMG
[ ] Beechwood City Flame thrower
[ ] Firefly Projects Minigun
[ ] Firefly Island Twin pistols
[ ] Outlook Park Micro SMG
[ ] Colony Island Double barreled shotgun
[ ] Middle Park West Flame thrower
[ ] Beechwood City Chainsaw
[ ] Castle Garden City Carbine Rifle
[ ] Star Junction Sword
[ ] Lower Easton Flame thrower
[ ] South Bohan Stubby shotgun
[ ] Fishmarket South Assault Rifle  
Percentage  ?.??%

Misc. Collectibles

Security Cameras

[ ] 1 [ ] 2 [ ] 3 [ ] 4 [ ] 5
[ ] 6 [ ] 7 [ ] 8 [ ] 9 [ ] 10
[ ] 11 [ ] 12 [ ] 13 [ ] 14 [ ] 15
[ ] 16 [ ] 17 [ ] 18 [ ] 19 [ ] 20
[ ] 21 [ ] 22 [ ] 23 [ ] 24 [ ] 25
[ ] 26 [ ] 27 [ ] 28 [ ] 29 [ ] 30
[ ] 31 [ ] 32 [ ] 33 [ ] 34 [ ] 35
[ ] 36 [ ] 37 [ ] 38 [ ] 39 [ ] 40
[ ] 41 [ ] 42 [ ] 43 [ ] 44 [ ] 45
[ ] 46 [ ] 47 [ ] 48 [ ] 49 [ ] 50
[ ] 51 [ ] 52 [ ] 53 [ ] 54 [ ] 55
[ ] 56 [ ] 57 [ ] 58 [ ] 59 [ ] 60
[ ] 61 [ ] 62 [ ] 63 [ ] 64 [ ] 65
[ ] 66 [ ] 67 [ ] 68 [ ] 69 [ ] 70
[ ] 71 [ ] 72 [ ] 73 [ ] 74 [ ] 75
[ ] 76 [ ] 77 [ ] 78 [ ] 79 [ ] 80
[ ] 81 [ ] 82 [ ] 83 [ ] 84 [ ] 85
[ ] 86 [ ] 87 [ ] 88 [ ] 89 [ ] 90
[ ] 91 [ ] 92 [ ] 93 [ ] 94 [ ] 95
[ ] 96 [ ] 97 [ ] 98 [ ] 99 [ ] 100

Percentage: ?.??%

Unique Stunt Jumps (USJs)

[ ] 1 [ ] 2 [ ] 3 [ ] 4 [ ] 5
[ ] 6 [ ] 7 [ ] 8 [ ] 9 [ ] 10
[ ] 11 [ ] 12 [ ] 13 [ ] 14 [ ] 15
[ ] 16 [ ] 17 [ ] 18 [ ] 19 [ ] 20
[ ] 21 [ ] 22 [ ] 23 [ ] 24 [ ] 25
[ ] 26 [ ] 27 [ ] 28 [ ]29 [ ] 30

Percentage: ?.??%

Safehouses

[ ] 1 [ ] 2 [ ] 3 [ ] 4 [ ] 5
[ ] 6 [ ] 7 [ ] 8 [ ] 9 [ ] 10
[ ] 11 [ ] 12 [ ] 13 [ ] 14 [ ] 15
[ ] 16 [ ] 17 [ ] 18 [ ] 19 [ ] 20
[ ] 21

Percentage: ?.??%

Meet All Drug Dealers

[ ] 1 [ ] 2 [ ] 3 [ ] 4 [ ] 5
[ ] 6 [ ] 7 [ ] 8 [ ] 9 [ ] 10
[ ] 11 [ ] 12 [ ] 13 [ ] 14 [ ] 15
[ ] 16 [ ] 17 [ ] 18 [ ] 19 [ ] 20
[ ] 21 [ ] 22 [ ] 23 [ ] 24 [ ] 25
[ ] 26 [ ] 27 [ ] 28 [ ] 29 [ ] 30
[ ] 31 [ ] 32 [ ] 33 [ ] 34 [ ] 35
[ ] 36 [ ] 37 [ ] 38 [ ] 39 [ ] 40
[ ] 41 [ ] 42 [ ] 43 [ ] 44 [ ] 45
[ ] 46 [ ] 47 [ ] 48 [ ] 49 [ ] 50
[ ] 51 [ ] 52 [ ] 53 [ ] 54 [ ] 55
[ ] 56 [ ] 57 [ ] 58 [ ] 59 [ ] 60
[ ] 61 [ ] 62 [ ] 63 [ ] 64 [ ] 65
[ ] 66 [ ] 67 [ ] 68 [ ] 69 [ ] 70
[ ] 71 [ ] 72 [ ] 73 [ ] 74 [ ] 75
[ ] 76 [ ] 77 [ ] 78 [ ] 79 [ ] 80

Note: You do not have to buy or sell. Just open the screen with the bag/trunk.

Percentage: ?.??%

Drug Warehouse Raid

Complete 1

Percentage  ?.??%

Golden Dragons

[ ] 1 [ ] 2

Percentage: ?.??%

REWARDS

Ambulance Missions  Infinite Sprint
Police Missions Double Body Armor
Firetruck Missions  Fireproof
Taxi Missions   All Bulletproof Taxis
L.C. Gun Club (5 medals)    Ammu-Nation Discount
Noodle Run (2 medals)   Regenerating Health
Excess Delivery (2 medals)  Expanded Drug Storage
Drug Trading Trophy How To Earn
Wooden Spoon    Lose $500
Platinum Syringe    Purchase Heroin
Diamond Pillbox Sell hallucinogenics
Jeweled Bong    Sell depressants
Silver Safe Make $2,000
Golden Binoculars   Find 40 dealers
Titanium Briefcase  Find 80 dealers
Jeweled Key to the City Own all 21 Safehouses
```